# Showing TabBar in DrawerNavigator screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I currently have this structure:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Store:{screen: Store}
  More: {screen: More,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'More',
      tabBarIcon: <Entypo name='dots-three-horizontal' size={25}/>,
      header: null
      },
    }
  },
  {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
                if (scene.route.routeName === "More") {
                  navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')
                }
                else{
                  jumpToIndex(scene.index);
                }
            },
        }),
      },
    )


const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
   Tabs: {screen: Tabs,
     navigationOptions: {
           drawerLabel: () => null
      }
   },
   Profile: {screen: Profile},
   Search: {screen: Search}
  },
  {
   initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
   headerMode: 'none',
   drawerPosition: 'right'
  }
)


export const Root = StackNavigator(
  {
  LoginScreen: {screen: Login},
  Drawer: {screen: Drawer},
 },
  {
   initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
  }
)
```

Everything works great. When I click (for example) 'Profile' the page is loaded normally and when click 'More', drawer menu opens up.

The functionality I would like to achieve is that I would like to show TabBar inside 'Profile' page(DrawerNavigator screen). How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
   Profile: {screen: Tabs},
   Search: {screen: Search}
  }
```

You can nest a navigator in another navigator. The Tabs navigator is a component and you can use that component as a "screen" for a different navigator.

A navigator is a component. And a screen must be a component.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but Profile screen should be a Profile(profile page) and not Tabs. I added Profile screen in Tabnavigator and when clicking Profile in DrawerNavigator I am being redirected to profile pag. I can see the TabBar below(That's what I was going for initially), only problem I have is that I would like to hide the "Profile" Tab from TabBar.